# .htaccess - redirect to new folder if file doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Currently when I visit my site I get presented with users.cgi, this works fine.

But what I would like to do is check if a file exists in my webroot and if it **doesn't** exist, then send the user to new/index.php

The file I'm looking for is `done.txt`

If it exists then carry on as normal, if not got new/index.php

This is my current .htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "LogIn Name"
AuthUserFile /user/local/idlist
Require valid-user
DirectoryIndex users.cgi
Options +ExecCGI
```

Can this be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

#if file exists then carry on as normal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#otherwise rewrite to /new/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /new/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The file is not actually being used by the webserver, but will be in the same folder. The users will never try to visit that page. I just want to check if it exists, and then redirect if it doesn't. Thx